# Unidentified space at the bottom of the page

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I was so thrilled what causes this page to have extra space at the bottom here is the link of the site http://www.intangible-logic.com/lezyne-yr6-4/ I have already checked every elements on the site but there was nothing like margin or bottom that may this is the sample snapshot of what I was trying to mean

[image]

Have been trying so hard to search just to solve this please help me

Comment: I applaud you for using linux :D

Comment: I dont get it though, what space?

Comment: The footer is inside the body, so it shouldnt be touching the bottom of the page or anything like that.

Comment: I mean the space just after the copyright statement at the very bottom of the page if you try to zoom-in the site on your browser and go to the bottom of the site you'll able to see a huge space on it that is the space that I want to remove from this layout, have been trying to look at the body, the divs on the header, body and footer but I couldn't see any styles that may cause this.

Comment: Ohhh you want to get rid of the space, gotcha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in the `.maxidrop-main` div. Removing that div takes away the space at the bottom. It may be a div that's not closed like @cryptic said.

Comment: hahaha thank you so much for providing me an eye to see that problem now I'll do the trick to solve this on CSS.:)

Comment: No problem, a second pair of eyes always helps!

Comment: @ChristopherPelayo so was it the missing closing DIV?

Comment: @cryptic this is actually a joomla module extension the divs were properly closed but I'll double check on that as well

Comment: @ChristopherPelayo They aren't properly closed, if you visit the link in my post where the page is validated against the W3C validator it will show many errors, the missing closing tag is one of them. Glad you got this fixed, but you should fix the other errors so they won't cause problems down the road.

Comment: @cryptic Thanks for the idea if it's possible that it's caused by an unclosed tag it might take me more time to fix it since it's a plugin and I still have to trace the codes so I just use the suggested solution here previously I could use a css code:

.level2 .floatck {
    overflow: hidden;
}

Answer (score 1):

Please set overflow:hidden property in #header

```
#header{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

problem is this element in header tag  `<div id="maximenuck"> ..... </div>`

Comment: thanks for the code but if I do this overflow hidden the dropdowns will never be shown anymore upon hoving every menu on the header div

Comment: instead of the header I could target the inner tags .level2 .floatck {
    overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: you can try  ovrflow :hidden on #maximenuck